# Reading from Random access file in c

Tags: c, file, struct

Hello programmers note I saw this code but this is puzzling me `fseek(fp, sizeof(e) * (id - 1), SEEK_SET)` not sure I understand what `sizeof(e)*(id-1)` is doing?

```
//program to read a specified employee's record from a random access
//file. The file was previously created and initialized to hold a maximum of 5000 records
//and some data was later stored in the file.
#include <stdio.h>

//Declare Employee structure
struct Employee
{
    int IdNo;
    char FName[20];
    char LName[20];
    float Pay;
};

typedef struct Employee EMP;

void main ()
{
    int id;
    FILE *fp;
    EMP e = {0, "", "", 0.0};
    fp = fopen("Employee.dat", "r+b");
    if (fp != NULL)
    {
        printf("\nEnter employee's id number (1-5000)");
        scanf("%d", &id);
        //locate the record, read it in, then close the file
        fseek(fp, sizeof(e) * (id - 1), SEEK_SET);
        fread(&e, sizeof(e), 1, fp);
        fclose(fp);
        if (e.IdNo != 0)
        {
            printf("Employee's record successfully retrieved from the file\n");
            printf ("Id: %d\n", e.IdNo);
            printf ("First Name: %s\n", e.FName);
            printf ("Last Name: %s\n", e.LName);
            printf ("Pay: %f\n", e.Pay);
        }
        else
            printf("Employee record retrieved from file is empty\n");
    }
    else
        printf("Error - could not open random access file\n");
}
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to 1) indent the code and 2) clarify what you're asking?

Comment: is it any better or you still need me to show you the code i am working on @Thanatos

Comment: I thought the code would have been useful, had you indented it.

Comment: @Thanatos oh ok i get you , but the guy posted the answer gonna re edit the question to fit the answer since i really wanted to get an idea of how to go through many records in a file.

Comment: @user2861799, do not edit your question to suit an answer. That defeats the purpose of the site.

Comment: @druciferre sorry but my question wasnt structured right so i restructured it to the simplest form which was figuring out what that fseek() was doing in the program as it was the key thing i was trying to understand.

Comment: @user2861799 I updated my answer, maybe it helps to approach your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`fseek`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fseek.3.html) moves the file position to a new location. When you then read from that stream, it will retrieve the contents at that location.

In your case, the position is `sizeof(e) * (id - 1)` from the beginning (`SEEK_SET`). This means position to the `id`th record (`sizeof(e)`) in your file

- the first record is at `sizeof(e) * (1 - 1)`, which is `0`
- the second record is at `sizeof(e) * (2 - 1)`, which is after the first record `sizeof(e)` bytes further
- ...

So, when you `fseek` with `id=2`, it will position at the second record and then read that record into the variable named `e`.

*Update:*

To address the comments to your question. If you want to go through multiple records, you can do it either record by record

```
fseek(fp, sizeof(e) * (id - 1), SEEK_SET);
fread(&e, sizeof(e), 1, fp);
// do something with record e
// seek and read further records ...
```

or read multiple records at once into an array of structs

```
EMP emps[10];
// ...
fseek(fp, sizeof(emps[0]) * (id - 1), SEEK_SET);
fread(emps, sizeof(emps[0]), 10, fp);
// do something with records in emps
```

or you can read one record after another without an intervening seek

```
fread(&e, sizeof(e), 1, fp);
// do something with first record
fread(&e, sizeof(e), 1, fp);
// do something with second record
// ...
```